# Semantic Segmentation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, image-segmentation

It's my second time of posting this question but in different words. I am new to AI and deep learning. I want to make a tool to replace the floor in a image with different patterns. I made a datasets of almost 250 pictures and stored them in a json file. Using trainMask R-CNN model I got some results (using Python), but I want to use JavaScript. I converted my model into `tf.js` format but I face different challenges, like how to load the model in `tf.js`, and how to predict.

Can any one help me to start segmentation in an easy and fast way for custom datasets. I don't understand `tf.js`.

Comment: Have you looked at the official Tensorflow tutorials? https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials

Comment: yes i check complete tutorials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To load a model in tf.js you can use the tf.loadGraphModel function

```
async function loadModel() {
    model = await tf.loadGraphModel("model/path");
    // do what you need with the model
}
```

For prediction take a look at the [tf.js API](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.12.5/#tf.Model.predict)

Comment: When i load the the model and run or call prediction get an error networktopology=null

Comment: @muhammad-jahanzaib-khan then you should ask a question specifying the code and the error so that the community can help you better reproducing your same error or understanding the mistake by the code